# simple alignment using gwt

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

[image: horizontal panel and two select item]

in the image is an **horizontal panel having two vertical panel** in it,

> application label and the select item

below is an vertical panel and

> environment and the select item

below is another vertical panel and that is added to a  horizontal panel , i want a gap between two vertical panel i tried with set spacing its not working please help , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of your panel wider than the width of a text box.

Comment: please can u help  me with these,     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805970/different-ui-settings-using-gwt